# Is there a high resolution ERwin data model (.emf) viewer?

Tags: viewer, .emf, erwin

Our data modelers are using ERwin v.8 and I need usable physical data models from it, however, the output is terrible being in a .emf format.  Viewing the images in a browser doesn't work as the text becomes too heavily pixelated when zooming to make it totally unreadable.  The "Windows Picture and Fax Viewer" does allow viewing but the text in the image is heavily clipped and I can't get a larger print out of the model.  Is there a way they can save it or is there a viewer I can use that would allow me to zoom in/out and print the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a lot to do with the display properties of the stored display.  Before you generate you EMF file.  Go to each stored display and set each one to normal zoom level, then generate you picture.
If you move to Erwin R9 the generation of HTML reporting like the old Report template builder is back!!